# No aparace mis datos guardados. (php/MySQL/SQL)

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli

Tengo un formulario conectado a MySQL pero cuando le meto la información no se registra y no la guarda en MySQL. Éste es el código en PHP:

```
<?php
  Include 'conexion.php';
  $nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
  $apellido=$_POST["apellido"];
  $correo=$_POST["correo"];
  $contraseña=$_POST["contraseña"];
  $telefono=$_POST["telefono"];
  //Consulta para insertar
  $insertar ="INSERT INTO tarjetas(nombre, apellido, correo, contraseña, telefono)
  VALUES ('$nombre','$apellido','$correo','$contraseña','$telefono')";
  $verificar_correo =mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM tarjetas WHERE correo='$correo'");
  $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$insertar);
  if (!$resultado) {
    echo "Error al registrar";
  }else {
    echo "Registro guardado ";
  }


//Cerra conexion
mysqli_close($conexion);

 ?>
```

Creo que el Problema es en la sentencia de SQL pero no se que esta mal. :'v

Y éste es el HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Estilos -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Plantilla</h1>
  <form action="php/registrar.php" method="post" class="form-register" onsubmit="return validar();">
    <h2 class="form_titulo">Introduzca sus datos</h2>
    <div class="contenedor-inputs">
      <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" class="input-48">
      <input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido" placeholder="Apellido" class="input-48">
      <input type="email" name="correo" id="correo" placeholder="Correo" class="input-100">
      <input type="password" name="contraseña" id="contraseña" placeholder="contraseña" class="input-48">
      <input type="tel" name="telefono" id="telefono" placeholder="Telefono" class="input-100">
      <input type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar" value="enviar" class="btn_enviar">
    </div>
  </form>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <script type="js/validar.js"></script>

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: tal vez detalle menor, pero la instrucción include va toda en minúsculas y tu la I la pones en mayúscula, igual cambia eso prueba y nos avisas @oscar hernan

Comment: El `Include` no daría error al escribirlo con `I` mayúscula, aunque es cierto que estamos acostumbrados a verlo con `i` minúscula. La inserción puede fallar por varios motivos: conexión no válida, consulta errónea (nombres de tablas o columnas), fallo debido a posible registro duplicado, fallo debido a que alguna de las variables es nula y esa columna no admite nulos ... nada de eso es controlado en tu código. Y, por otra parte, el código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de Inyección SQL, deberías usar consultas preparadas para evitar ese tipo de ataques.

Comment: tienes razón me puse a hacer un ejercicio y lo comprobe gracias @A.Cedano

Comment: te agradezco tus correciones y por el consejo de inyeccion sql me pondre al tanto de eso.

Comment: Hola veo que nadie te a dado la bienvenida a [es.so], bienvenido! Por favor termina el [tour] para que sepas en funcionamiento de la página y de paso obtener tu primera medalla :)